# authentication token in the header instead of cookie?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, http, authentication

I am building an asp.net application using webApi. It will have mobile clients too.
My mobile developer suggests that he will sent the authentication token in the header and also he will expect the authentication token in header instead of cookie.

The popular way of asp.net authentication is cookies or URI. How do I make it work with headers? or Can I ?